# Tabulator.js grid implementation

Tags: tabulator

What is the best way to implement a tabulator table to an existing css grid?
Thus meaning, instead giving a widthGrow size to each column, defining a start/end column for each columns.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please provide some additional information to your question, it is hard to understand what you are asking for from your question. what do you mean by existing CSS grid? and what you you mean for a start/end column for each column?

Comment: Sure. My whole webpage relies on a column/row grid created with CSS Grid. (for example 12 columns of 1fr each with 12px gap) On the top and side corners there is some navigation content. That leaves the middle cells free to show some data there. In my case I assign a tabulator table to these empty space. (lets say 7 columns of the original 12). The only configuration option of tabulator columns that is close to what I wish, is "fitColumns"+"widthGrow". But this does not take into account the gaps of my original grid and data columns don't align perfectly with other outside-table content.

Comment: I mean if I have the fields Name, LastName and Age in my data, I could give them widthGrow of 3+3+1 = 7 (as many as my main grid empty columns), so that they align to the general grid. But they are still 12px off because widthGrow doesn't take into account any gaps between columns.

Comment: Tabulator is not built using CSS grid, there is no way to implement it in that fashion, you can choose a layout mode similar to what you are hoping for and tweak the styling to match. but there is no way to make the internal layout use grid because that would fight against tabulators internal layout system